# Dynamic / run-time loading of Assembly C from A where both C and A reference B

Tags: c#, reflection, reference, assemblies, runtime

I already have the following scenario working:

- Assembly `A.exe`: Calling WinForms application.
- Assembly `B.dll`: Class library hard-referenced by `A`.
- Assembly `C.dll`: Compiled at run-time and references `B` (classes inherit from `B` classes).

`A.exe` compiles some code to `C.dll` at run-time, loads the assembly and invokes `((B.BaseClass) C.DerivedClass).BaseMethod();`

If I compile `C` to disk as a DLL, it picks up `B.dll` in the same folder. However, I do not want to write `C.dll` to disk at all.

What approach would be best to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do something like this (register the AssemblyResolve somewhere early in your app, such as in Program.cs or App.xaml.cs):

```
    //Since we'll be dynamically loading assemblies at runtime, we need to add an appropriate resolution path
    //Otherwise weird things like failing to instantiate TypeConverters will happen
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;

private Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    var domain = (AppDomain)sender;

    foreach (var assembly in domain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        if (assembly.FullName == args.Name)
            return assembly;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I kind of get what you are saying but I am not sure what the method is doing. When this event is triggered, shouldn't my code be telling the run-time how to access assemblies already loaded in the current appdomain? I'm new to reflection so trying to understand your solution better.

Comment: By the way, I cam always instantiate an object from Assembly `B` to make sure that it is loaded before `C` ever gets called. Not sure if that is relevant.

Comment: This is a good way of providing B if it is already loaded. If not, you can `Assembly.LoadFile(string Path)` in the handler, it is its purpose.